# Property 'CommandArgument' is WriteOnly

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, asp.net-3.5, sender, commandargument

I have the following line in my code, inside the click event handler of an ImageButton:

```
Protected Sub FinaliseBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles FinaliseBtn.Click, SubmitPaymentViaChequeBtn.Click
   Dim str as String = sender.commandargument.ToString.ToLower
End Sub
```

Both Controls are `ImageButton`'s. However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Property 'CommandArgument' is WriteOnly.
```

Can anyone see why I'm getting this error as usually I can read from a CommandArgument inside an event handler. In fact, surely thats their main use!

Thanks.

Comment: The error is not "ReadOnly" but "WriteOnly", means that property has setter only, not getter

Comment: @ika urgh good point, sorry for wasting time. I'll rewrite my question.

Comment: what type of control is this? and can you show your method signature? BTW - `sender` is usually an `Object`, you should be accessing the `CommandEventArgs` (normally aliases as `e`)

Comment: @RPM1984 Thanks for your comment, I've edited my question to show the Sub.

Comment: @RPM1984 If the sending Object has a CommandArgument attribute, whats wrong with Object.CommandArgument? :S

Comment: @RPM1984 Also, e.CommandArgument is not a member of System.EventArgs :S. Thanks for your help with this so far though, much appreciated!

Comment: @Curt - yes, sorry, im thinking of LinkButton (CommandEventArgs). Try my answer out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've wired up an event for **EventArgs**, but trying to retrieve **CommandArgs**.

This should be your method:

```
Sub ImageButton_Command(sender As Object, e As CommandEventArgs) 
         If (e.CommandName = "Sort") And (e.CommandArgument = "Ascending") Then
            Label1.Text = "You clicked the Sort Ascending Button"
         Else
            Label1.Text = "You clicked the Sort Descending Button"
         End If
      End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried the following: 

Dim _btn As ImageButton = TryCast(sender, ImageButton)  Select Case _btn.CommandArgument

 However, I get the error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

Cheers

Comment: Sorry, it looks like one of my buttons is a UserControl containing an ImageButton, not just 2 ImageButtons! However, this answer helped me find that solution, thanks :D

Comment: Yes, that would have been helpful information previously. :) Glad you got it sorted.